# logic of this piece of bashquery

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Not able to understand what this is doing

```
TEST_DEBUG=${TEST_DEBUG:-false}
[[ "$TEST_DEBUG" == false ]] || TEST_DEBUG=true
```

and in further down the code in multiple places..this code is present

```
$TEST_DEBUG && echo 1>&2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TEST_DEBUG=${TEST_DEBUG:-false}
```

This assing `false` to `$TEST_DEBUG` unless it already has a value (see *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`).

```
[[ "$TEST_DEBUG" == false ]] || TEST_DEBUG=true
```

The condition inside `[[ ... ]]` returns true when `$TEST_DEBUG` has the value of `false`. If it returns false, i.e. the value is different, then `$TEST_DEBUG` is assigned `true`.

```
$TEST_DEBUG && echo 1>&2
```

This runs the `echo` only if `$TEST_DEBUG` is set to `true`.

`echo` without parameters just outputs an empty line to standard output. `1>&2` redirects standard output to standard error, so in this case, the empty line is printed to standard error.

Answer (score 0):

In first statement, the operator :- Tests if `TEST_DEBUG` variable exists within the braces and is set, if it is set, it is assigned the value in the TEST_DEBUG if not set or has a null value, it is assigned false.

`TEST_DEBUG=${TEST_DEBUG:-false}`

in the second statement

`[[ "$TEST_DEBUG" == false ]] || TEST_DEBUG=true`

Bash checks if `TEST_DEBUG` is set to false, if not, it assigns it a value true.

for more information on how this works in detail, please check out GNU bash documentation.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs